# How to unit-test a AWS Lambda use lambda-local with mocha?

Tags: unit-testing, lambda, aws-lambda, mocha.js

**Background**

I am working on a project that is build with **Serverless** framework with  **serverless-appsync-plugin**. I implemented a single endpoint(AWS Lambda) to handle all the requests generate from Appsync through graphQL. The endpoint will route the request to the corresponding function to perform the operation.

**Problem**

Now that I have developed around 10+ operations, I want to automate the process of unit-testing. For simplicity, I decided to run that single endpoint as a lambda locally for all the testing (against running appsync-offline).

So, I used [lambda-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-local) with [mocha](https://mochajs.org/). However, I am not able to get a test-case to fail, based on the response I got from the lambda.

```
it('db should have a user of uId: 123',  async function () {
  lambdaLocal.execute({
    event: makeUserEvent({userId: '123'}),
    callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: false,
    lambdaPath,
    callback: function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(1)
        expect.fail(null, null, 'You are not supposed to be here') //should fail here
      } else {
        console.log(2)
        // some checking here, may fail or may not fail
        expect.fail(null, null, 'return fail if the userId is 234') //should fail here too
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(3)
})
```

In both of the situation I want it to fail, it is not failing the test cases for either `callback('failed', null)` or `callback(null, 'success')`.

**So, what is the right way to make the lambda-local to fail a test case?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the test finishes without mocha registering that the assertions in `lambdaLocal.execute` failed. So it will always pass.

Instead of using the callback parameter you could return a promise, or await the `lambdalocal.execute` and then do your assertions.

For example (using Promises):

```
it('db should have a user of uId: 123',  function () {
  return lambdaLocal.execute({
    event: makeUserEvent({userId: '123'}),
    callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: false,
    lambdaPath })
 .then(
    (data) => {
        console.log(2)
        // some checking here, may fail or may not fail
        expect.fail(null, null, 'return fail if the userId is 234') //should fail here
    },
    (err) => {
        console.log(1)
        expect.fail(null, null, 'You are not supposed to be here') //should fail here
    })
}
```

Alternatively change signature of the function that is passed to `it` to take an additional parameter (usually called `done`) which will then be used by mocha to pass a function that can be used to signalise that the test finished. See the [mocha documentation](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) for more info.

Comment: First, the code works. But, there are still something I don't understand.
1. In my code, the console.log(1) runs before console.log(3). Does that mean that the return callback is executed before the outside block?
2. How did you convert the original callback-style to the promise-style? More precisely, how do you know the lambda.execute is a promise that you can chain a .then() after it?
3. How do you know the first parameter inside the .then() is the data and the second parameter is the error?

Comment: 1.: the problem is less the order of execution, but that the error that is thrown by the assertion is not caught by mocha because it's in an independent callback  (that's why we return the promise). 2.: I found that information by looking at the test files for [lambda-local](https://github.com/ashiina/lambda-local/blob/develop/test/test.js). 3.: that's just how `Promise.then` works, see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)